# nonstandard namespace in corba idl

Tags: .net, corba, iiop

I'm using IIOP.NET to connect to corba servers. The servers are enterprise level machines and deployed by world renowned vendors, so they all implement standard corba IDL files. More specifically, all of them conform to 3gpp standards.

In the 3gpp standard idl files the pragma prefix is defined to be **3pggsa5.org**. I've used the IDL to CLS compiler, which comes along with IIOP.NET, to generate a dll. It gets generated with the same namespace i.e. **3pggsa5.org**. However this dll is unusable in .NET because the namespace starts with an integer.

If I try and put an underscore before 3, .NET recognized that but it can't connect to corba server as the interface or IDL has changed now. I've also read somewhere that namespaces generated for java classes from corba idls are the same as corba/idl namespaces. So this should be a problem there as well. Certainly 3gpp standards are industry level standards, and it is not possible that they don't work. Am I missing something?

Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you still need it? I can try to fix it in IIOP.NET

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper idl compiler that prefixes those bad namespaces (3gpp) with a proper char. Then, your code will work ;)

Or just change the namespace in the idl files yourself.